# Error when trying to register a user using Firebase Auth service on the client side. Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuejs3

I am trying to do authentication and registration by email and password using the internal authentication system within Firebase and Vue3 on the client. I get the following error when I trying to register a user:

> Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed).
> POST
> http://localhost:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AndHereIsTheKeyFromFB
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Component with registration form:

```
<template>
  <p><input type="text" placeholder="Email" v-model="email" /></p>
  <p><input type="password" placeholder="Password" v-model="password" /></p>
  <p><button @click="register">Submit</button></p>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import {getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword} from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();

const email = ref('')
const password = ref('')
const router = useRouter()
const register = () => {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email.value, password.value)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('Successfully logged in!');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.code)
        alert(error.message);
      });
}
</script>
```

main.js with firebase configurations:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "key",
    authDomain: "authDomain",
    databaseURL: "dbUrl",
    projectId: "Id",
    storageBucket: "sB",
    messagingSenderId: "msgSenderId",
    appId: "Id"
};

initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

if (location.hostname === "localhost") {
    connectAuthEmulator(getAuth(), "http://localhost:9099");
}
```

I also tried to change the hostname from localhost to 127.0.0.1, but this did not affect the result in any way. My experience with Firebrace and authentication through it is small, so I will be glad of any help in this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the issue with some changes to main.js configuration file contains the following lines
from this:

```
if (location.hostname === "localhost") {
    connectAuthEmulator(getAuth(), "http://localhost:9099");
}
```

to this:

```
if (location.hostname === "localhost:8080") {
    connectAuthEmulator(getAuth(), "http://127.0.0.1:9099");
}
```

I don't know why, but the changing of port and localhost to IP like indication worked for me :)